# How to merge two dataframes and retain values in multiple rows?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

is the merge function the appropriate way to join the Dataframes 1 and 2 to get the Desired Dataframe?

Dataframe 1:

| animal | category | Add-Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| wolf | land | 24/09/22 |
| eagle | sky | 24/09/22 |
| robin | sky | 24/09/22 |
| bear | land | 24/09/22 |
| cod | water | 24/09/22 |
| salmon | water | 24/09/22 |

Dataframe 2:

| category | Tier |
| --- | --- |
| land | 1 |
| sky | 2 |

Desired Dataframe:

| animal | category | Add-Date | Tier |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| wolf | land | 24/09/22 | 1 |
| eagle | sky | 24/09/22 | 2 |
| robin | sky | 24/09/22 | 2 |
| bear | land | 24/09/22 | 1 |

The Desired Dataframe is Dataframe 1 with irrelevant categories removed and  the appropriate Tier brought across with the category.

I was trying merge, join, etc. but unsure of the best approach or if I am making an error.
Any help much appreciated on the code or method to use.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pandas Merging 101](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53645882/pandas-merging-101)

Comment: Also, separately - What if the columns were named differently?

E.g. if in Dataframe 1 was 'Location' instead of 'category' and Dataframe 2 was 'Prop_Location' instead of 'category'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can perfom an inner join by using [**`pandas.merge`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.merge.html) to grab the `Tier` column from `df2`.

```
out = df1.merge(df2, on='category')

display(out)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, will test this in a moment. What if the columns were named differently?

E.g. if in Dataframe 1 was 'Location' instead of 'category' and Dataframe 2 was 'Prop_Location' instead of 'category'?

Comment: In that case, you'll need to pass two more arguments, `out = df1.merge(df2, left_on='Location', right_on='Prop_Location')`

Answer (score 1):

```
df_merged = pd.merge(df1, df2, how = 'left', on = 'category')
```

out:

```
   animal category  Add-Date  Tier
0    wolf     land  24/09/22   1.0
1   eagle      sky  24/09/22   2.0
2   robin      sky  24/09/22   2.0
3    bear     land  24/09/22   1.0
4     cod    water  24/09/22   NaN
5  salmon    water  24/09/22   NaN
```

you can drop NaN values if needed by

```
df_merged = pd.merge(df1, df2, how = 'left', on = 'category').dropna()
```

out:

```
  animal category  Add-Date  Tier
0   wolf     land  24/09/22   1.0
1  eagle      sky  24/09/22   2.0
2  robin      sky  24/09/22   2.0
3   bear     land  24/09/22   1.0
```